# How to plot points in Latex

Tags: latex, graphing, tikz, overleaf

[image: Example]

I'd like to draw a graph similar to the one in the image uploaded. where V1,V2 and I1,I2 are known values. I do not care about the dashed lines or even the theta angle. All i want is a linear function going through points.

I've tried this with the `tikz` -package and just couldn't do it. I'm a beginner to Latex so sorry for any misused terminologies and poor explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using the `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5,yscale=1.5]
  \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[right] {I (A)};
  \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) node[above] {V (Volt)};
  \draw[line width=1pt] (1,1) -- (4,4) node[midway, above right, xshift=0.2cm] {m = $\tan(\theta)$};
  \draw[dotted] (1,0) node[below] {$I_1$} -- (1,1);
  \draw[dotted] (0,1) node[left] {$V_1$} -- (1,1);
  \draw[dotted] (4,0) node[below] {$I_2$} -- (4,4);
  \draw[dotted] (0,4) node[left] {$V_2$} -- (4,4);
  \draw[dotted] (1,1) -- (4,1);
  \draw (1,1) +(0:0.5cm) arc (0:45:0.5cm) node[midway, right] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

This is the output you're gonna get with this snippet, which is as close as I could come to your original image:

[image]

You can obviously tweak the parameters to your liking, for example:

- The first two `\draw` lines draw the X axis and the Y axis respectively, so you can tweak the labels accordingly.
- The third `\draw` line is the one that actually draws the line, this one goes from (1,1) to (4,4). You can logically modify the V1, V2, I1 and I2 points to known values, the ones I wrote are arbitrary. Make sure to make these coordinates fit with the dotted lines coordinates, which are the four `\draw` lines that follow. Should be easy to see how.
- If you want the slope label to be in a different position, you simply have to tweak the coordinates and the 'above right' parameter in the third `\draw` line, which is the one that draws this text label.
- The eighth `\draw` line draws the dotted line that forms the base of the triangle.
- The last `\draw` line draws the angle icon. If you'd like to make it bigger or smaller or change its label to something else, you can do so by modifying this line.

You can remove/modify any of these lines individually because each tweaks a separate thing.
I hope this suits your needs.